# how to handle cursor-based paging in facebook

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is one data about someone's status on facebook. I want to crawl its all '`likes`', '`comments`'. From the crawled data, we can see that the `paging` information is given. But I don't know how to build one query url to get more `likes`, `comments`. Could any one help me ? Thanks.

```
{u'picture': u'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
 u'likes': {
                u'paging': 
                        {
                            u'cursors': 
                                {u'after': u'MzUyMTIyMDg4MzAzMTIx', 
                                u'before': u'MjMyNjMyNzc2OTM3MDkw'
                                }
                         }, 
                u'data': 
                    [
                        {u'id': u'111111111111111111', u'name': u'xxx1'}, 
                        {u'id': u'111111111111111112', u'name': u'xxx2'}, 
                        {u'id': u'111111111111111113', u'name': u'xxx3'}, 
                        {u'id': u'111111111111111114', u'name': u'xxx4'}, 
                    ]
            }, 
 u'from': {u'id': u'123412341234', u'name': u'xxx5'}, 
 u'comments': 
    {u'paging': 
        {u'cursors': 
            {u'after': u'WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZOVGsyTnpBNE9UTTNNVE13TXpRMU9qRTBNalEwTmpRNE1UVT0=', 
            u'before': u'WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZOVGsyTmpVMk5USTNNVE0xTlRnMk9qRTBNalEwTlRRM01URT0='
            }
        },
    u'data': 
        [
            {
                u'from': 
                    {u'id': u'21341234', 
                        u'name': u'asdfasdf'
                    }, 
                 u'like_count': 0, 
                 u'can_remove': False, 
                 u'created_time': u'2015-02-20T17:51:51+0000', 
                 u'message': u'asdffda', 
                 u'id': u'12341234', 
                 u'user_likes': False
             }, 
             {
                u'from': 
                    {u'id': u'12344312', u'name': u'xxx6'},
                u'like_count': 0, 
                u'can_remove': False, 
                u'created_time': u'2015-02-20T20:40:15+0000', 
                u'message': u'You too josh love your posts', 
                u'id': u'431234567', 
                u'user_likes': False
             }
      ]
  }, 
u'source': u'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1234',
u'privacy': 
    {u'allow': u'', u'deny': u'', u'friends': u'', u'description': u'', u'value': u''}, 
u'actions': [
                {u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx/posts/44444444444', u'name': u'Comment'}, 
                {u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx/posts/33333333333', u'name': u'Like'}
            ], 
u'properties': [
            {u'text': u'01:00', u'name': u'Length'}
               ], 
u'link': u'https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=22222222222', 
u'object_id': u'333333333333', 
u'created_time': u'2015-02-20T17:18:35+0000', 
u'message': u'TGIF!!! Have a phantabulous Friday!!', 
u'updated_time': u'2015-02-20T20:40:15+0000', 
u'type': u'video', 
u'id': u'12321_456654', 
u'status_type': u'added_video', 
}
```

Comment: What is the query you are using to get this data? In general the likes object has a Json array of all the likes called data, of the status, i.e. if you query `/id/statuses` you will see data in the form  `"data": [
          {
            "id": "YYYYYYY", 
            "name": "XXXXXX"`
          }` where each id is the person behind the like/comment and the arraylength will give you the number

Comment: @Slartibartfast  Thanks, I think I solved it. In the facebook, when we crawl some new feeds, it is possible that we cannot crawl all the information.